# Wakanda Page Prototype Custom Save

Tags: wakanda

I have 3 tables, `sale`, `detail_sale`, and `item` like this:

```
sale {id, date}

detail_sale {id, sale, item, qty}

item {id, name}
```

So, in wakanda how do I insert table `sale` and `detail_sale` in one page with page prototype?

That I read in [Wakanda Documentation](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Datasource/Server-Datasources/save.301-607761.en.html), I insert `sale` table fist and then insert `detail_sale`. Can I insert `sale` and `detail_sale` in one time?

Comment: [Wakanda Documentation](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Datasource/Server-Datasources/addNewElement.301-607725.en.html) this solve one page to insert 2 table, second problem is how to relate detail_sale to item

Comment: [Wakanda Documentation](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Datasource/Server-Datasource-Related-Attributes/set.301-626509.en.html) this solve second problem, relate detail_sale to item

Answer (score 2):

the `save` method is asynchronous so you can not know when it's done,
So the best thing is to make nested calls, so in the `onSuccess` callback (of sale) you can call the save of 'detail_sale'